# How to have localStorage value of true?

Tags: javascript, string, boolean, local-storage

I was wondering if its possible for localStorage to have a Boolean value instead of a string?

Using JS only no JSON if its impossible or can be done in JS a different way please let me know thanks

http://jsbin.com/qiratuloqa/1/

```
//How to set localStorage "test" to true?

test = localStorage.getItem("test");
localStorage.setItem("test", true); 

if (test === true) {
  alert("works");
} else {
  alert("Broken");
}



/* String works fine.

test = localStorage.getItem("test");
localStorage.setItem("test", "hello"); 

if (test === "hello") {
  alert("works");
} else {
  alert("Broken");
}

*/
```

Comment: No. However you could save an empty string for `false` and rely on type coercion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I was wondering if its possible for localStorage to have a Boolean value instead of a string?

No, [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) only stores strings. To store more rich data, people typically use JSON and stringify when storing and parse when retrieving.

Storing:

```
var test = true;
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test));
```

Retrieving:

```
test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
console.log(typeof test); // "boolean"
```

You don't need JSON for just a boolean, though; you could just use `""` for false and any other string for true, since `""` is a "falsey" value (a value that coerces to false when treated as a boolean).

Comment: @GoogleFailedMe: The `JSON` object is provided by all modern browsers, and also IE8: http://caniuse.com/#search=json